# meteor this.params._id is undefined stick

Tags: meteor

I'm a student learning `meteor.js`.

`iron:router` is using:

```
this.route('postEdit', {
  path: '/posts/:_id/edit',
  data: function() { 
  console.log(this.params._id);
  return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

And this error is displayed:

> this.params._id value is undefined76kndYuWd2KDX2eeE...

Why does `undefined` has that stick value?

`postEdit` call has:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'postEdit'}}">Edit</a>
```

Originally, it was 76kndYuWd2KDX2eeE due to URL being `localhost:3000/posts/undefined76kndYuWd2KDX2eeE/edit`...

Please, help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update to `iron@1.0.9`, that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a problem with `iron:router@1.0.8`, just run `meteor update` again and it will automatically update to the latest version of `iron:router` which solves this problem.

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1359